# Usage of "Chances are ..."

Tags: meaning

In on other SE post, when talking about the manager from previous job who is again (after some time ) to become manager at another company, it says:

> Chances are he realized his mistakes from before and learned.

I would translate this as neutral "Maybe he realized..." (correct?) but I was wondering does it also imply any level of probability that such thing happened (like "he most probably realized..." or "there is a slim chance that he realized..."?

Comment: *....realized his mistakes **from the past** and learned..."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chances are](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/chances+are) implies that something seems likely to have happened.